# Fazer uma div se ajustar horizontalmente ao conteúdo

Tags: css, css3

Quero fazer com que uma DIV se ajuste perfeitamente ao conteúdo inserido dentro dela.

Ao digitar um texto que excede a largura máxima (max-width) o texto quebra e vai para baixo, porém a div não fica perfeitamente alinhada ao texto, parecendo que há uma margem para direita.

Utilizando `display: inline-block;` funciona até a linha precisar ser quebrada devido a largura máxima.

Segue código fonte como exemplo: https://codepen.io/Lucas7796/pen/ewejyZ

[image: exemplo]

Comment: Para fazer o texto ocupar toda a largura da div coloca text-align:justify no <p>

Comment: Já havia testado isto antes mas vi que as palavras ficaram muito espaçadas entre si.

Atualizei no Codepen para mostrar o resultado:

https://codepen.io/Lucas7796/pen/ewejyZ

Tentei também o 'width: min-content' junto com o min-width, porém a largura sempre fica o tamanho setado no min-width, o que no meu caso também não serve, pois não está dinâmico

Comment: Cara essa é a forma com o browser renderiza texto alinhados a esquerda que é o padrão, se vc não quer que sobre espaços tem que justificar o texto no contaier, ou então colocar a medida exata do container até onde vc quer que quebre a linha, mesmo assim se tiver mais de duas linhas fica assim http://prntscr.com/o9a020

Comment: Valeu cara, o meu problema é que tenho um container que precisa ser dinâmico pois vai receber textos em vários idiomas e dependendo do idioma o texto ficará maior ou menor, em alguns casos gerando esta quebra de linha. Vou usar a estratégia de setar o tamanho do container de acordo com o idioma. Obrigado!